# Derivatives of the direction cosine matrix

Tags: rotations, kinematics

Consider the standard rigid body rotation problem of a rigid body B(Oxyz) rotating G(OXYZ).  Let $\mathbf e_i$ represent the unit vectors of the B frame and let $\mathbf E_i$ represent the unit vectors of the G frame {i: 1 to 3}. The direction cosine matrix (DCM) from the B frame to the G frame,$^GR_B$, has ij elements $\mathbf E_i$ $\cdot$ $\mathbf e_j$ where {i, j: 1 to 3}.

If each element of either DCM is left in scalar product form (e.g. for $^GR_B$, $\mathbf E_i$ $\cdot$ $\mathbf e_j$) rather than an evaluated form (e.g. for $^GR_B$, cos($\mathbf E_i$, $\mathbf e_j$)), we can differentiate the DCM, with respect to time and with respect to either frame (using the fact that the unit vectors of a given frame are fixed in the same frame; using the left superscript on d to denote the frame for which the derivative is taken with respect to).

Equation (1):

$$\frac{^Gd}{dt}(^GR_B) = \frac{^Gd\mathbf E_i}{dt} \cdot\mathbf e_j + \mathbf E_i \cdot\frac{^Gd\mathbf e_j}{dt} = \mathbf E_i \cdot\frac{^Gd\mathbf e_j}{dt}  
$$

Equation (2):

$$\frac{^Bd}{dt}(^GR_B) = \frac{^Bd\mathbf E_i}{dt} \cdot\mathbf e_j + \mathbf E_i \cdot\frac{^Bd\mathbf e_j}{dt} = \frac{^Bd\mathbf E_i}{dt} \cdot\mathbf e_j
$$

When the scalar product is evaluated, however, the B and G derivatives reduce to a simple time derivative of a scalar.

Equation (3):

$$\frac{^Bd}{dt}cos(\mathbf E_i, \mathbf e_j) = \frac{^Gd}{dt}cos(\mathbf E_i, \mathbf e_j) = \frac{d}{dt}cos(\mathbf E_i, \mathbf e_j) =  \frac{d}{dt}(^GR_B)
$$

It would seem that equation (3) indicates that equation (1) is equal to equation (2).  However, if such holds then I am having trouble seeing it just from the form of equation (1) and (2).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I dont get what is $\cos(E_i, e_j)$. Isn't it just $\cos(E_i, e_j) = E_i \cdot e_j$? Why do you think is it something different?

Comment: The issue isn't the definition of the scalar product.  Rather it is one of seeing the equivalence between equation (1) and equation (2), both of which are predicated upon differentiating the scalar product in the dot product form (rather than in the evaluated scalar form) with respect to each frame of reference.  The underlying motivation for the first two equations is working with angular velocity vectors that are derived from the B and G derivatives of the direction cosine matrix.